# How to i write protobuf 0:0 message?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, proto

I don't understand how to write `0: 0` in proto message.

```
0: 0
0: 0
166: 9fc1171b9ae3179d4e
2: test
3: 1
```

I tried like this:

```
message test {
    int32 unknown = 0;
    int32 unknown2 = 0;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Zero is not a valid protobuf field number. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do here, and why? Is this some framing piece? Or ..? (because you're asking how to do something that isn't legal in the protocol; the only answer is "you don't" - but sometimes people use zeros to partition data *separately* to the protobuf piece)

Comment: any more context? I'd love to help, but you're asking ... well, it would be like asking "I want to.write an element with an empty name in XML, `<>` - how do I do that?" - if we can understand your goal a bit better, we can offer better guidance